# how to link the pbrun session to the originating session?

Tags: unix, ssh, ksh, sudo, pbrun

```
ssh host1 -l user1
who am i
$ user1    pts/5 
pbrun su - service1
who am i
$ service1     /dev/pts/2
```

So how can service1 session determine that is was launched by user1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me;

```
w>w.log
# account
grep "$0" w.log | cut -f1 -d " "
# pty
grep "$0" w.log | cut -f2 -d " "
```